# Snowball Stemmer [Java]

Tags: java, stemming, porter-stemmer, snowball

I am currently using the Snowball Stemmer (Porter2) in my Java Project to stem words etc.  However, it stems words that either don't necessarily need to be stemmed or stem's them too much? For example, `online -> onlin`, `why -> whi`, `raise-> rais`, `appreciate -> appreci`.

Is there any way that I could try prevent this unnecessary stemming as I would like it to give me words that are meaningful, as well stemming words that need to be stemmed, such as `treating -> treat`, `records -> record`, `development -> develop` etc by implementing some sort of dictionary that would avoid these words being stemmed? Or if there are any other stemmer similar to Snowball that are less precise in their stemming abilities?

Thanks for all the help.

Here is my function.

Comment: What's your objective of stemming? search?

Comment: @bigOTHER -- my goal is to gain tweets from the internet, stem the words in the tweet and remove the stop words so I am left with the basic words in the tweet for analysis.  However, some of the words are too stemmed and don't really want this, which is why I was looking for it to be less precise

Comment: These stemmed words are good because Portar exists for search objective,  ie it doesnt matter if a stem is a real origin, what matters is that it is the same for the whole family of words.

Comment: @bigOTHER -- so you do not think it will matter? you think i will still be able to analyse the tweets using the really precise nature of Snowball?

Comment: what kind of analysis you are doing?

Comment: @bigOther - term frequency analysis, where I check how many terms are within my data set, and i also going to check terms that are related with each other, like if they are commonly tweeted with each other, like cancer and treatment etc.

Comment: I think you dont need an aggressive stemmer for this, and may be you dont need a stemmer at all. Stemmer is grouping by family of word but in your case , `development` should not treated as `developing` since they are not the same word or are they?.

Comment: @bigOTHER -- yeah I did want a stemmer, just not as aggressive as snowball? are there any other stemmer you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main job of Porter Stemmer is grouping words into a set of stems. These stemmed words are good because Porter exists for search objective, ie it doesn't matter if a stem is a real origin, what matters is that it is the same for the whole family of words.

As you are working for the objective of **Term frequency analysis** and **Collocations**, I suppose you need a light stemmer or a minimal one.

You can check this article for [stemmers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/choosing-a-stemmer.html) used in Lucene. You can notice:

> *minimal_english*
>
> The [EnglishMinimalStemmer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishMinimalStemmer.html#EnglishMinimalStemmer()) in Lucene, which removes
>   plurals

Comment: will EnglishMinimalStemmer remove endings such as ing, ment etc too?

Comment: @JohnLewis no , that's for plural forms only. if you want more, try kstem or lovins.

Comment: just implemented Lovins and it seems thats much more precise than Snowball haha

Comment: @JohnLewis   Porter is the best but not for your case.

Comment: for my case, what would you recommend? I would like to remove more than just plurals, such as ending in ing, ent, etc.

Comment: I think just plurals,  "ing" change the POS of word and  the meaning.